# How use Kafka to create a stream of API Requests (POST/GET etc.)

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I'm working on a thesis. I developed 4 different microservices (REST APIs). I would like to use Kafka a message queue/broker to support a large number of users. I may also place the microservices behind a HAPI Proxy. How can I use Kafka to stream requests and respond accordingly. I'm using Node.js. I think I haven't grasped Kafka. My Prof, suggested I try it to act as a broker but I'm blank right now. How do I tell Kafka I want it do a POST or GET etc? Do I plug kafka into my REST APIs?

Comment: Kafka cannot really be used in a request/response type system such as an HTTP POST or GET request. You push a message into Kafka, another microservice would eventually consume that message and perform some data processing on it. But there is no real clear way for the initial service that put the message into Kafka to know that the message was processed, or get any kind of response from it. It's certainly *possible*, just not in any way efficient.

Comment: If the goal is to eventually have some message processed without the requesting client caring about when it happens or getting any kind of result back then Kafka will work just fine.